# How do I get rid of the little man in a google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Which google map option is used to hide the little man in a google map?

[image]

Here are my map options

```js
mapOptions.zoom = 18;
mapOptions.zoomControl = true;
mapOptions.center = new window.google.maps.LatLng(mapCoordinates.latitude, mapCoordinates.longitude);
mapOptions.disableDefaultUI = false;
mapOptions.draggable = true;
mapOptions.styles = "";
mapOptions.disableDoubleClickZoom = true;
mapOptions.mapTypeControl = false;
```

Answer (score 7):

Teh little man is named `Pegman` and the control is streetViewControl

```
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(initLat, initLng),
                zoom: initZoom,
                streetViewControl: false,  //don't show the  pegman 
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                mapTypeControl:false,
                scaleControl: true, 
                tilt: 0,
                styles: mlwStyles                   
            };
```